# How do I get the correct output for the object e1?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing an app that reads a file from the URL when the user input the url address, where the file is located. It will read the data values and then inputs the data values to each class object. When I write the setText command (outside of the while loop), it gets an error when I type e1.getName(). It asks me to initialize e1. I did that, but when I run the app, getName() shows null. I want the name of the employee. So, first here is what the class looks like:

```
public class Employee {
        private String name;
        private double salary;
        private String id;
        private String office;
        private String extension;
        private int yearsofservice;

//default constructor
Employee(String string, double d, String string2, String string3, String string4, int i)
{
}

//copy constructor
Employee(Employee eData)
{
name = eData.name;
salary = eData.salary;
id = eData.id;
office = eData.office;
extension = eData.extension;
yearsofservice = eData.yearsofservice;
}
//Define the methods
public String getName()
{
//Return the object's name
return name;
}
public void setName(String n)
{
//set the object's name to the given name
name = n;
}
public double getSalary()
{
return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double s)
{
salary = s;
}
public String getId()
{
return id;
}
public void setId(String ID)
{
id = ID;
}
public String getOffice()
{
return office;
}
public void setOffice(String o)
{
office = o;
}
public String getExtension()
{
return extension;
}
public void setExtension(String e)
{
extension = e;
}
public int getYearsOfServ()
{
return yearsofservice;
}
public void setYearsOfServ(int yos)
{
yearsofservice = yos;
}

}
```

Second, this is the code in the MainActivity or code for the app:

```
public void displayEmployees(View view)
   {
    EditText edt1;
    TextView tv;
    String urlfile;

    //Declare three references to Employee object
    Employee e1;
    Employee e2;
    Employee e3;



    //Create reference for EditText and TextView

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_file);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_main);

    //Store the URL address when user input it and assign the input
    //to variable (reference) urlfile 
    urlfile = edt1.getText().toString();

    //Use try/catch to check if the file opening on the web succeed
    try
    {
        //Create an URL object that read urlfile
        URL file_url = new URL(urlfile);

        //try to open the file from the web
        Scanner fsc = new Scanner(file_url.openStream());

        //As long as there is data to read, continue
        //reading the file
        while(fsc.hasNext())
        {

            //tv.append("\n" + fsc.nextLine());//This is for testing to display data

            //Create three Employee objects and input the data values
            //from urlfile to each object
            e1 = new Employee(fsc.nextLine(), Double.parseDouble(fsc.nextLine()), 
                    fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), 
                    Integer.parseInt(fsc.nextLine()));

            e2 = new Employee(fsc.nextLine(), Double.parseDouble(fsc.nextLine()), 
                    fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), 
                    Integer.parseInt(fsc.nextLine()));

            e3 = new Employee(fsc.nextLine(), Double.parseDouble(fsc.nextLine()), 
                    fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), fsc.nextLine(), 
                    Integer.parseInt(fsc.nextLine()));

            //e1.setOffice(Integer.parseInt(data));
            //...Continue with other class objects with their respective set method
        } 

        tv.setText("The name of the employee: " + e1.getName()); //The error is here!

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        tv.setText("Error: Invalid URL Address or File Does Not Exist");
    }


}
```

}

Lastly, the file looks like this (Note: each value is in a seperate line):
Sally L. Smith
086244
100000.00
Ramsey Hall 3814
9976
9
Lucy Bayer
288567
39500.57
Cullimore Hall 100
6000
1
William Harris
732241
120000.00
GITC 165
7533
4

Comment: Are you sure you enter the while loop?

Comment: Yes, I did. I typed in my question, inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Employee` constructor you use in the while loop does nothing with the data you give him. So you will never get any name on your Employee objects

```
public Employee(String name , double salary, String id, String office, String extension, int yearsofservice)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.id = id;
    this.office = office;
    this.extension = extension;
    this.yearsofservice = yearsofservice;
}
```

Comment: What is the reference this mean?

Comment: For an object, `this` is a reference to itself. So inside the `Employee` class, `this.name = name` is a way to put the `name` from parameters to its own `name` property (`private String name`) without naming conflict.

More on `this`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: So, the code above, do I put that in the copy constructor and replace what I have it there?

Comment: This has to replace the default one, the one you use in the while loop

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I figured out how to input the data from the file into the class object. I just had to create some local variables to store the data values, and then put them into set method.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that fsc has no next element(while loop doesn't initiate e1). Write System.out.println("text"); inside while loop and tell if it is being called.

Comment: It is not being called. The only thing that my app shows is  the String message I typed for the catch statement.

Comment: An Android application needs permission to access internet, did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions